# I am confused about B-Tree Index

Tags: mysql, sql

I read MySQL [document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-btree-hash.html) about index, but I don't understand this statement:

> Any index that does not span all AND levels in the WHERE clause is not
>   used to optimize the query. In other words, to be able to use an
>   index, a prefix of the index must be used in every AND group.

What does it mean? For example, I have a table A, and it has an index (index_part1,index_part2,index_part3).

I have read these example below the statement,but I am still confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This basically means that index can be used for `where` clauses where the conditions are connected by `AND` but not `OR`.  So, an index on `a, b` and be used for:

```
where a = 10 and b = 100
```

However, it cannot be used if you replace the `and` with an `or`.

The concept of "span" means, in essence, common subclauses.  So, MySQL might be smart enough to use the index for:

```
where (a = 10 and b = 100 and c = 'a') or
      (a = 10 and b = 100 and c = 'b')
```

The index works because these have a common subclause.

However, the index could not be used for:

```
where (a = 10 and b = 100 and c = 'a') or
      (a = 10 and c = 'b') or
      (b = 100 and c = 'c')
```

There is no common set of columns in the clauses that is also in the index.

Comment: thanks,if the index is (a,b) and i use where(a=10 and b= 100 and c='a') or (a=10 and c=10) ,does it use the a index?if i use  where(b= 100 and c='a') or (b=10 and c=10) does it use b index?

Comment: @wangyiran . . . Yes and no.  To use the index `(a, b)`, you need `a` in the comparisons.